# Can I pass to a Stargate Back and Forth?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to objects that enter a Stargate from the wrong side?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/what-happens-to-objects-that-enter-a-stargate-from-the-wrong-side)

Can a person/object pass through a stargate and go back again without having to shutdown the gate's wormhole, and without dialing again?

Because, when they sent a UAV to the volcanic planet, they control it in realtime and sending them back signals and video.

That being said, why can't they open a stargate from Earth and let the other side pass it. No DHD needed then, this is from the episode where the DHD fell to the ocean. Ok... the SGC does not know they cannot dial back, also the power might be cut off, but if ever they felt that their team is missing from sometime, can't they send a drone to see if everyone's OK, then they can report that they cannot use DHD somehow and ask the Earth team to open it to their side.

Comment: That would be a cool feature, get one stargate to request an incoming wormwhole from another!

Comment: Like remote dialing, I guess

Comment: @AidanO The stargates did communicate some low-level protocol to each other, there's no reason they couldn't. Of course, some of their attempts to modify stargate firmware resulted in minor disaster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was explained many times through the series, how this works.

- Solid matter can only pass from side that opened the gate.
- Energy can pass both ways.

Because radio signals are energy, they can pass both ways. Thus allowing real-time communication with people and devices at the other side.

You can read more [on the Wikia](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate).

Comment: what happens if a solid matter enters from the other side?

Comment: @Sid It is destroyed. This is mentioned eg in the series 2 episode Prisoners, where several prisoners tried to escape by entering the wormhole from the wrong direction, to SG1's despair.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In _Prisoners_, they tried to "ride the wave" out, which would be fatal on either side of the wormhole.  But +1 otherwise, going backwards would destroy any matter that passed entirely through the event horizon.

Comment: How does the show handles "Nothing is created nor destroy, everithing transforms" with matter-destructing doors? EDIT: this is a real interrogation, if this is interesting enough i'll write it as a question

Comment: @Ergrith: the stargates work by converting humans to energy, moving them from one gate to another, then "reconstituting" them into matter. (Ep: "48 Hours") If someone rides the kawhoosh, or enters the gate from the wrong side, they're destroyed: ie: they're turned into energy and never turned back again...